# predicting the possibility of Active members becoming Inactive?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a database of members, some are active and some are inactive.

I want to predict the possibility of Active members becoming Inactive?

Should I run the AML on the inactive members (no splitting) and when I publish the model i pass in the active members?

I have tried many AML datasets before however usually you will have a column that contains the values you want to predict (Active-Inactive) (True-False) (Red-Black-White) but i never tried having only one value to trina your model with.

Comment: What are the data features that you have in your dataset that related to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to train your model with both active and inactive members.  I would split your dataset so there are examples of active and inactive members in both your training and your test set.

Let's discuss why we split the data.  Remember that with supervised learning, you need data with labeled examples.  For example, let’s say I want to predict how much a house will cost based on its square footage and zip code.  To train my model, I need a dataset of existing houses with their square footage, zip codes, and prices, like this:

SquareFootage ZipCode Price 
2000          48075   200,000 
3000 48075 300,000 
4000 48075 400,000 
5000 48075 500,000

In this example, square footage and zip code are my features (things that influence the thing you want to predict) and price is my label (the thing that you want to predict).  I could train a model on some data like the above, and then use the trained model to predict prices, given only a square footage and zip code.

So, the reason I split the data is to provide most of the data to train the model (it will process the data to figure out correlations between the features and labels in the “train model” module), but we want to hold back some of that labeled data to test the model that we built.  Then, we can compare the price value that the trained model generates against the actual labeled price value in the test dataset (in the “score model” module) to see how well the model is performing.  (We can’t use the same data for both...the model is built using the training data, so it will perform pretty accurately with that; we hold back unused data to test.)

So, for your example, I would try a random split so there are examples of both active and inactive members (that is your label - inactive or active) and you will also need to provide relevant features that influence activity.

Comment: Hi Jennifer, what a small world, i have attended your sessions on Azure Machine Learning at MS Ignite NZ this year. you really influenced me to learn AML, i even stole your "Who survived the Titanic" demo and i demo'd to my boss and he liked it and asked me to do more research and now i am building a prototype :).. i have a list of members who joined a Gym, some of them left(inactive) the others still going(Active) . if i run a classification algorithm on both members with 70/30 split can i then still be able to use the model on the Active members to predict how likely they will leave the Gym?

Comment: @AlexMouses - It's great that you know Jennifer but... this isn't a discussion forum - not the place to share these stories. And... if you have additional questions, either edit your question or post a new question. Don't bury additional questions in comments. (and if all you need is a clarification, then great - just post that comment, without the preamble).

Comment: @AlexMouses - If your data is just a list of names and whether they are inactive or active, that won't work for prediction.  What you need is features - various data points that may influence whether or not they remain active. Do you have access to things like gender, amount of time they have belonged to the gym, whether or not they have signed up for a class, maybe weight or BMI, maybe the amount of time until summer/bathing suit season, etc.  You need to find contributing factors that could influence their decision to remain active, and the ML algorithm will help find the most relevant ones.

Comment: @JenniferMarsman-MSFT Thanks Jennifer, yeah, i am using various features, still cleaning up the data though to choose whats relevant and whats not. As you said in the session 90% of the time will be data cleaning :) . i am planning to use the two class decision jungle algorithm is that good or do you recommend trying others? Thanks

Comment: @AlexMouses The best algorithm really depends on your data, but the Azure Machine Learning Algorithm cheat sheet can give you some hints on what may work best: http://aka.ms/AzureMachineLearningCheatSheet